# @nrwl/nx error when creating new apps and libs

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nrwl

I'm getting errors that seem to stem from linting during the creation of a new lib or app via nrwl's nx.

I've taken an existing angular/cli project and added @nrwl/schematics to it (via the `ng add @nrwl/schematics` command).

I then try to add a new app: `ng add app new-app`.

This results in the following error:

`nx format:write "--untracked" "--quiet"`

And the errors specified are for angular html templates - for every angular notation (e.g. [counter]=..., *ngIf, #menu show error for [, * and # respectively).

Any idea how this might come about and how to solve this? Does it even matter, as it seems the files are being created anyway?

UPDATE:
When I add *.html to the `.prettierignore` file, the error does not appear. It seems like prettier rules "catch" angular template syntax as error. Any idea how to fix this?

UPDATE #2:
Figured it out - the prettier version was old. Angular HTML support for prettier is available from version 1.15.x.

Answer (score 0):

In the rare occassion someone manages an old legacy code with an old prettier:

Angular HTML support for prettier is available from version 1.15.x.

https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html

Would have saved me half a day's work to find this earlier :)